# ssl with client authentication between cxf and IIS resulting in SocketException and SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, ssl, cxf

So, I've been wrestling with a two way ssl setup between Tomcat6/Camel/Cxf to IIS6 the last few days.

A quick overview: I have a cxf consumer running in Camel in Tomcat, which calls a webservice hosted with a third party on IIS. The third party is using a 'valid' certificate, whereas we are using a self-signed certificate. IIS is configured to require client authentication.

I've gotten to the point where cxf is configured correctly, and mutual authentication is being performed.

Some gotcha's I needed to fix to get there:

- allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true
- https.protocols=TLSv1 (else java would send a SSLv2 client hello in the middle of the handshake)
- remove the default ciphersuite filter that I copied from most CXF examples, it was too strict

All certificates, firewall settings etc. are correct, as I'm able to do a call to the third party using curl and I get a valid SOAP response back.

**The problem**: **I get a timeout exception** when sending a SOAP POST message from my application.

Looking into the ssl debug log there are some strange errors (I tried to remove all unnecessary stuff):

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
http-9203-1, setSoTimeout(120000) called
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
http-9203-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 111
http-9203-1, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 2454
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1354816328 bytes = { 63, 194, 181, 182, 56, 251, 234, 198, 234, 92, 162, 175, 243, 127, 133, 182, 0, 237, 102, 9, 37, 133, 141, 3, 175, 120, 34, 92 }
Session ID:  {36, 10, 0, 0, 166, 131, 36, 81, 251, 181, 83, 154, 76, 240, 235, 82, 39, 135, 239, 235, 231, 195, 17, 225, 220, 59, 105, 207, 116, 185, 114, 172}
Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Compression Method: 0
***
Warning: No renegotiation indication extension in ServerHello
%% Created:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
** SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
*** Certificate chain
***
Found trusted certificate:
*** ServerHelloDone
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
http-9203-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 262
http-9203-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 124, 172, 175, 239, 103, 187, 134, 164, 206, 241, 145, 41 }
***
http-9203-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
http-9203-1, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
http-9203-1, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 84, 207, 104, 255, 19, 151, 27, 11, 159, 84, 124, 216 }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 54 CF 68 FF   13 97 1B 0B 9F 54 7C D8  ....T.h......T..
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 365
0000: 50 4F 53 54 20 2F 69 73   61 2E 64 6C 6C 2F 41 43  POST /isa.dll/AC
http-9203-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 365
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 1200
0000: 3C 73 6F 61 70 3A 45 6E   76 65 6C 6F 70 65 20 78  <soap:Envelope x
http-9203-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 1200
default-workqueue-1, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 20
```

This is the first handshake without client authentication (as IIS is using re-negotiation to get the client certificate). Note that a first attempt to post the SOAP message is already been made (is that normal?).

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: false
Is secure renegotiation: false
*** HelloRequest (empty)
Warning: continue with insecure renegotiation
%% Client cached [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
%% Try resuming [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5] from port 58460
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
default-workqueue-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 159
default-workqueue-1, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 5416
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
%% Created:  [Session-2, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
** SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
*** Certificate chain
***
Found trusted certificate:
*** CertificateRequest
*** ServerHelloDone
matching alias: servercert
*** Certificate chain
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
default-workqueue-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 909
*** CertificateVerify
default-workqueue-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 150
[Raw write]: length = 155
default-workqueue-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 17
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 242, 160, 100, 95, 172, 14, 166, 71, 158, 148, 220, 42 }
***
default-workqueue-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
default-workqueue-1, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 17
default-workqueue-1, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 115, 32, 183, 236, 113, 63, 144, 117, 126, 132, 150, 67 }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-2, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
default-workqueue-1, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
default-workqueue-1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
default-workqueue-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 18
default-workqueue-1, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
default-workqueue-1, called closeSocket()
default-workqueue-1, called close()
default-workqueue-1, called closeInternal(true)
```

The second handshake sends the client certificate to the server, I removed the detailed logging but the certificate was found and ok-ed. As you can see this handshake already ends with an error (without any delay in time).

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
default-workqueue-1, setSoTimeout(120000) called
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
default-workqueue-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 111                                      
default-workqueue-1, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 2454
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
Warning: No renegotiation indication extension in ServerHello
%% Created:  [Session-3, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
** SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
***
Found trusted certificate:
*** ServerHelloDone
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
default-workqueue-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 262
... no IV used for this cipher
default-workqueue-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 130, 65, 225, 31, 41, 14, 21, 42, 102, 176, 151, 245 }
***
default-workqueue-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
default-workqueue-1, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
default-workqueue-1, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 125, 78, 165, 103, 115, 60, 111, 169, 180, 174, 0, 169 }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-3, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
default-workqueue-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 365
default-workqueue-1, handling exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
default-workqueue-1, called close()
default-workqueue-1, called closeInternal(true)
default-workqueue-1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
default-workqueue-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 18
```

Then a third handshake is performed (normal?), and again a POST of the SOAP message is done (the write of the application date). After that POST the logging waits until the socket timeout expires (I've put it on 2 minutes or 10 secs, doesn't make a difference), after which I get a SocketTimeoutException. I tried switching to SSLv3 or 2, but that gives exactly the same result.

Any ideas what it causing this behaviour?

Comment: What JDK are you using ?

Comment: On top of my head, since I'm not at work today, JDK6u23. Unfortunately I couldn't experiment with other versions because the server is not under my control. I also searched the Oracle bug database a bit, but couldn't find anything relevant immediately.

Comment: We had the same issues connecting a java client to an IIS server. On Windows with JDK6u22 we also had to set the system property. On AIX we didn't have the issue and were able to connect just fine. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tlsreadme2-176330.html

Comment: Ok so I'm not alone, that's something. Not sure what you mean though, if you set the allowUnsafeRenegotiation property you got it to work? Or you never got it to work with that specific JDK version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should anyone ever encounter this same problem, [this](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/bce0fb87-79ea-40cd-963f-239545b61a12.mspx?mfr=true) solved it eventually for me. I asked our third party to set this flag to true, since we only communicate with each other that shouldn't be a problem. Setting the flag to true disables renegotation, thus skipping the part in the ssl setup where it went wrong.